# How to check remotely Windows credentials with python

Tags: python, windows, credentials, rdp

I have a few old machines that I would like to verify the credentials each of them has is correct and math. All machines don't have SSH or WMI enabled.
On Linux, for example, I used Paramiko to SSH to servers and detected an error or successfully connected.

RDP is not required, just verify the credentials.
Could you please help me how to check it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show any work that you've already done, such as research in modules to assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a similar problem a couple weeks ago using `pypsexec` along with windows login credentials, where I didn't have ssh access to the servers.

You could try something like this.

```py
from pypsexec.client import Client

# for each windows server
try:
    c = Client("server", username="username", password="password")
    c.connect()
    c.cleanup()
    c.disconnect()
except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection failed, " + str(ex))
```

You can find out more information here [pypsexec](https://github.com/jborean93/pypsexec).